# Check if data containing a-z or A-Z

Tags: python

I made to request to get random user and add them to my database for testing.
Unfortunately, some of those datat is not in English.

Example.

[image]

That lead to bad data, and break my table, that I'm rendering.

[image]

---

## I'm thinking

to check the api data to see if, it's an english character.
If it is, insert it to the database, otherwise, get out of the system.

```
if firstname.isalpha():
    cur.execute(sql,args)
else:
    sys.exit()
```

But for some reason, it still inserted, :(

Any hints / suggestions on this issue will mean a lot to me.

---

## I have

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import random
import requests
import time
import sys
import datetime

from random import randrange
from datetime import timedelta
from time import gmtime, strftime

def random_date(start, end):
    """
    This function will return a random datetime between two datetime
    objects.
    """
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = (delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + delta.seconds
    random_second = randrange(int_delta)
    return start + timedelta(seconds=random_second)

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-03-27 11:16:32', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime()), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p", gmtime())


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="*********",  # your password
                     db="db-local")       # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

# The first line is defined for specified vendor
mac = [ 0x00, 0x24, 0x81,
    random.randint(0x00, 0x7f),
    random.randint(0x00, 0xff),
    random.randint(0x00, 0xff) ]

device_mac =  ':'.join(map(lambda x: "%02x" % x, mac))
device_mac = device_mac.replace(":","").upper()


cpe_mac = '000D6766F2F6'

url = "https://randomuser.me/api/"
data = requests.get(url).json()
firstname = data['results'][0]['user']['name']['first']
lastname = data['results'][0]['user']['name']['last']
email = data['results'][0]['user']['email']
gender = data['results'][0]['user']['gender']


age_range_options = ["<15", "15-25", "25-40","40+"]
age_range = random.choice(age_range_options)

ip = ".".join(map(str, (random.randint(0, 255)
    for _ in range(4))))

host_name = 'crontab'
os = 'iPhone OS 9.0'
visit_count = 1

rand_date = random_date(d1, d2);

created_at = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
updated_at = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

sql = ('''INSERT INTO visitors (device_mac,cpe_mac,firstname, lastname, email, gender, age_range,ip,host_name,os,visit_count,created_at, updated_at) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''')

args = (device_mac,cpe_mac, firstname, lastname, email, gender, age_range,ip, host_name,os,visit_count, created_at, updated_at)

if firstname.isalpha():
    cur.execute(sql,args)
else:
    sys.exit()

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Would "prfzfndfj" be considered proper english?

Comment: "_That lead to bad data_". How so? It looks like a perfectly legitimate name to me. Consider fixing your charts so they can render any kind of text, rather than limiting your inputs to the kind of text it can currently render.

Comment: Anything that containing English alphabet. I would love that.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094498/how-can-i-check-if-a-python-unicode-string-contains-non-western-letters

Comment: check if all the letters are ascii or utf-8 encoded. Since there are no arabics or chinese letters in this set, this will filter out all E-mail_adresses not using latin letters.(Of course it won't filter out german or italian or something like that. But if you use the ascii set, this in inprobably to happen, there are letters like `äöü` in german and other languages, you can filter them out, too

Comment: @Kevin : See my table, that I just uploaded.

Comment: @ihue https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha `isalpha` method is locale-dependent. If you absolutely just need 'A-Za-z' then regex it.

Comment: @woozyking : Thanks. I'll look into that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like `عالي` **is** *alpha*numeric... just in another *alpha*bet:

```
>>> a = u"عالي"
>>> a.isalpha()
True
```

Indeed, if your entire stack handles unicode properly, it should all work. Based on the table you uploaded, the only issue is the initial-finding code isn't handling Arabic characters properly.

---

If you want to keep your app western-centric instead of internationalizing it properly, you could always check for all letters to be in  the *latin* alphabet:

```
valid = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
def islatin(c): return c in valid
```

Note this will also ban chars like `é` and `ô`... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094498/how-can-i-check-if-a-python-unicode-string-contains-non-western-letters) for more thorough solutions.

Comment: This also won't only keep English (though I suspect OP doesn't want that),  it will happily accept any word in another language that happens to only use [A-z].