# How can i check string is Thai language that return boolean like isalpha()

Tags: python, regex, thai

I'm trying to check `str` that is only Thai character or not by using `regex` or any if it can solve

I'm trying to use

```
re.compile(u"[^\u0E00-\u0E7F']|^'|'$|''")
ret = regexp_thai.sub("", s)
```

to slice another language or digit 
by the way it just only slice not for return boolean

I expect output like

```
s = "engภาษาไทยที่มีสระ123!@"
regexp_thai = re.compile(u"[^\u0E00-\u0E7F']|^'|'$|''") 
ret = regexp_thai.sub("", s)
print(ret)             # ภาษาไทยที่มีสระ
print(isthai(ret))     # True
```

`u0E00-u0E7F` is a unicode of Thai language
How can I write `isthai` function

Comment: Basically `bool(re.match("^[\u0E00-\u0E7F]*$", test))` should evaluate to `True` iff `test` only consists of Thai characters. Fine tuning for punctuation et al is necessary yet.

Comment: Wow, that what I want thx you @MichaelButscher it's SOLVE!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what might be the desired output. However, I'm guessing that we like to capture the Tai letters, which based on your original expression, we might just want to add a simple list of chars, wrap it with a capturing group and swipe our desired Tai letters from left to right, maybe similar to:

```
([\u0E00-\u0E7F]+)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/BanFlL/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([\u0E00-\u0E7F]+)"

test_str = "engภาษาไทยที่มีสระ123!@"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /([\u0E00-\u0E7F]+)/gmu;
const str = `engภาษาไทยที่มีสระ123!@`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BanFlL/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Reference

[Regular Expression to accept all Thai characters and English letters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615740/regular-expression-to-accept-all-thai-characters-and-english-letters-in-python)

Comment: It makes me an idea but it's not my desire output sorry

Comment: This is a very good answer.  You've got functioning code. You've got a visual showing how the regex works.  You've got a link to a website that lets you tweak the regex until it does exactly what you want.  If this was the Stackoverflow Olympics, and I was a judge, I would give your answer a perfect 10!