# Categorize the dataframe column data into Latin/Non-Latin

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to categorize latin/non-latin data through Python. I want the output to be 'columnname: Latin' if it's Latin, 'columnname: Non-Latin' if it's non-latin. Here's the data set I'm using:

```
name|company|address|ssn|creditcardnumber

Gauge J. Wiley|Crown Holdings|1916 Central Park Columbus|697-01-963|4175-0049-9703-9147

Dalia G. Valenzuela|Urs Corporation|8672 Cottage|Cincinnati|056-74-804|3653-0049-5620-71

هاها|Exide Technologies|هاها|Washington|139-09-346|6495-1799-7338-6619
```

I tried adding the below code. I don't get any error, but I get 'Latin' all the time. Is there any issue with the code?

```
if any(dataset.name.astype(str).str.contains(u'[U+0000-U+007F]')):
    print ('Latin')
else:
    print('Non-Latin')
```

And also I'd be happy if someone could tell me how to display the output as "column name: Latin", column name being iterated from dataframe

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: name:Non-Latin
company:Latin
address:Non-Latin

This is my first time on stack overflow. Forgive me for any mistakes made :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a Python unicode string contains non-Western letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094498/how-can-i-check-if-a-python-unicode-string-contains-non-western-letters)

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 not exactly I guess

Comment: you're getting Latin all the time because of `any()`.  You need to use [Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) not `any()`.  Just `apply()` the function written in the duplicate question.  Your question is close enough to be considered a duplicate.  If you need to understand how to `apply()` a function, then you should re-phrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what need - if check if any value has non latin values or all values have strings with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':[u"هاها",'a',u"aهاها"]})

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/3308844
import unicodedata as ud
latin_letters= {}
def is_latin(uchr):
    try: return latin_letters[uchr]
    except KeyError:
         return latin_letters.setdefault(uchr, 'LATIN' in ud.name(uchr))

def only_roman_chars(unistr):
    return all(is_latin(uchr)
           for uchr in unistr
           if uchr.isalpha()) 

#check if any
df['new1'] = np.where(df['name'].map(only_roman_chars), 'Latin','Non-Latin')
#check if all
df['new2'] = np.where(df.name.str.contains('[a-zA-Z]'), 'Latin','Non-Latin')
print (df)

    name       new1       new2
0   هاها  Non-Latin  Non-Latin
1      a      Latin      Latin
2  aهاها  Non-Latin      Latin
```

Comment: I'm new to python. Sorry for my ignorance. What does is_latin function do here?

Comment: @Shri - it test characters in loop - each value separately

Comment: Sure, @jezrael I will. I'm still trying out a few iterations of this solution. Will update once done :)