# Pyparsing for unicode letters

Tags: python, unicode, pyparsing

I need to use pyparsing for unicode characters. So I tried simple example from their github repository with French character `cédille` and gives error.

My code

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas
greet = Word(alphas) + "," + Word(alphas) + "!"
hello = "Hello, cédille!"
greet.parseString(hello)
```

and it gives error

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "!" (at char 8), (line:1, col:9)
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: `alphas` appears to be pure ASCII only. There's a definition `alphas8bit` which is either misnamed or also not helpful.

Comment: `alphas8bit` dates back to early Python2 time, when the 128-255 alpha characters (with bit8 set, hence the name) were added.

Answer (score 2):

Pyparsing has the `pyparsing_unicode` module that defines a number of unicode character ranges with definitions for `alphas`, `nums`, and so on within each range. Ranges include `CJK`, `Cyrillic`, `Devanagari`, `Hebrew`, `Arabic`, and others. The `greetingInGreek.py` and `greetingInKorean.py` examples in the examples directory show a couple of these in action.

Your example, using the Latin1 set, will look like:

```
from pyparsing import Word, pyparsing_unicode as ppu
intl_alphas = ppu.Latin1.alphas
greet = Word(intl_alphas) + "," + Word(intl_alphas) + "!"
hello = "Hello, cédille!"
print(greet.parseString(hello))
```

Prints:

```
['Hello', ',', 'cédille', '!']
```

`alphas8bit` will probably be kept for legacy support, but new applications should use `pyparsing_unicode.Latin1.alphas`.

Comment: In python 2.7 this still gives error `pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "!", found '\xa9'  (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)`

Comment: That looks like you forgot to declare the source file's encoding, or failed to mark the string as a Unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

`alphas` is apparently English / pure ASCII only. The following appears to work:

```py
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, alphas8bit
greet = Word(alphas+alphas8bit) + "," + Word(alphas+alphas8bit) + "!"
hello = "Hello, cédille!"
greet.parseString(hello)
```

This is Unicode, so there is nothing particularly "8-bit" about the character *é*; but if the documentation is at least approximately correct, I guess it will still break with slightly more exotic accented characters (anything not available in Latin-1, like Czech or Polish accented characters, or go extreme and try Vietnamese).

Maybe explore the `unicodedata` module to get a proper enumeration of "alphabetic" characters, or find a third-party module which exposes this Unicode feature properly.

Comment: Indeed, `"Hello, cǔdille!"` still gives me a traceback.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094498/how-can-i-check-if-a-python-unicode-string-contains-non-western-letters for a couple of approaches, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187349/python-regex-for-unicode-capitalized-words for some other ideas. I *think* the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92438/stripping-non-printable-characters-from-a-string-in-python can be adapted to do what I propose, but I haven't investigated properly.

Comment: In python 2.7 still get error `pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "!", found '\xa9'  (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)`