# Python 3 Word Count by Unicode Language

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, word-count

I have texts that contain multiple languages in them. I want a word count that only records the words that occur with the Greek unicode character set using Python 3. Something like:

```
wordCount = 0
theText = open(file.txt, 'r')
for word in theText.split():
    if GreekUnicodeCheck(word):
        wordCount += 1
print(wordCount)
```

I have considered checking if a Greek letter is in every word like so:

```
wordCount = 0
theText = open(file.txt, 'r')
greekChars = ['α', 'β', 'γ', 'δ', 'ε', ...]
for word in theText.split():
    if any(letter in word for letter in greekChars):
        wordCount += 1
print(wordCount)
```

I think that should work, but the character set becomes quite large when you account for all the combinations of capitalization, diacritic marks, etc. (I'm working with Classical Greek). Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: [The second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094498/how-can-i-check-if-a-python-unicode-string-contains-non-western-letters) points to a alphabet detector that can be installed with 'pip install alphabet-detector'.  The detector code is [here](https://github.com/EliFinkelshteyn/alphabet-detector).  It can be used to detect greek unicode characters and other languages.  For greek ad = AlphabetDetector() and then use ad.is_greek(word)

Comment: Thanks Darryl, that's a good lead. I'll try it out!

Comment: You can convert to decomposed Unicode normal form (using `unicodedata.normalize`). This will separate diacrits from their base letters. Then you can check for the base letters only.

Comment: Brilliant. That's the answer I need. Thank you, Lenz.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that much though. Have a look on [this website](https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/unicode-characters-in-python.html). All the greek letters are listed there and I used a python script to convert it into this list:

```
greekSymbols = [\u0394, \u03A9, \u03C0, \u03F4, \u03BB, \u03B8, \u03B1, \u0302, \u0302, \u0302, \u0302, \u03B1, \u03B2, \u03B3, \u03B4, \u03B5, \u03B6, \u03B7, \u03B8, \u03B9, \u03BA, \u03BB, \u03BC, \u03BD, \u03BE, \u03BF, \u03C0, \u03C1, \u03C2, \u03C3, \u03C4, \u03C5, \u03C6, \u03C7, \u03C8, \u03C9, \u0391, \u0392, \u0393, \u0394, \u0395, \u0396, \u0397, \u0398, \u0399, \u039A, \u039B, \u039C, \u039D, \u039E, \u039F, \u03A0, \u03A1, \u03A3, \u03A4, \u03A5, \u03A6, \u03A7, \u03A8, \u03A9, \u03F4]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. It just might be enough. The difference is that this is a modern Greek character set. The problem with Classical Greek are accents, breathing marks, and a few other possible marks that mostly occur on vowels. The possible permutations of any of these marks on any of the appropriate letters grows quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get a list of all possible Greek characters using only the Python standard library is to use the [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) library to search by character name.

```
import unicodedata
greekChars = [chr(i) for i in range(0x110000) if 'GREEK' in unicodedata.name(chr(i), '')]
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This is a big part of what I was looking for.