# How to drop rows if text in column if fully latin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, filter

i have a dataframe with column sent:

```
sent
"error was found"
"я ищу новый error"
"загрузка завершена"
"new file is uploaded"
```

as you see some rows are fully latin strings, some are mixed and some are fully non-latin. i'd like to drop rows with fully latin string rows. so desired output is:

```
sent
"я ищу новый error"
"загрузка завершена"
```

how could i do that?

P.S.

I consider letters like ĄŻĆ latin as well

Comment: Do you consider letters like `ĄŻĆ` latin as well?

Comment: @matszwecja yes i do

Comment: You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094498/how-can-i-check-if-a-python-unicode-string-contains-non-western-letters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can remove lines that has no Cyrillic letters.

```
import pandas as pd

sent = ["error was found",
"я ищу новый error",
"загрузка завершена",
"new file is uploaded"]

df = pd.DataFrame(sent, columns=['sent'])
df = df[df['sent'].str.contains('[а-яА-Я]')] # filter dataframe

print(df)
```

****Output****

```
                 sent
1   я ищу новый error
2  загрузка завершена
```

Comment: That works for the example use case, but doesn't account for e.g. Greek text.

Comment: @9769953 what do you mean exactly it doesn't account Greek text?

Comment: This keeps Cyrcillic letters, but if the input contains Greek text, it isn't kept also dropped, just like Latin letters.

Comment: The thing is that this method approaches the problem from the other side (trying to keep everything that is not Latin, instead of removing everything that is Latin), which is harder, since it needs to contains all non-Latin possibilities.

Comment: @9769953 Actually it tries to keep cyrillic only, which is only a narrow subset of non-Latin.

Comment: @matszwecja Sorry, I don't get your point. The OP asks for fully-Latin strings to be removed. If this solution only keeps Cyrillic, it will also remove Greek, Japanese and other text types. That is not what the question asks, because it removes more than asked for.

Comment: "The thing is that this method approaches the problem from the other side (trying to keep everything that is not Latin...)" - it's not trying to keep everything that is not Latin, neither is it removing everything that is Latin. It only keeps things that contain Cyrillic, which as you said does not meet posted requirements (any non-Cyrillic string that is not Latin will get removed while according to the requirement it should be kept) and makes me wonder why this answer got accepted.